# Upload file from form post data using fine-uploader

Tags: file-upload, fine-uploader

I'm trying to upload post form data of a file using fine uploader, I've got a working uploader however it only works in the browser by selecting a file.

I would like to be able to send a file to a page which fine uploader would upload, here's an example using postman:

[image]

Comment: "I would like to be to be able to send a file to a page" - sorry I don't know what this  means

Comment: Like using post form data to send a file to upload.php

Comment: And where are you going to get this file from if you don't want to use a file input element or drop zone?

Comment: And you can't send files to "pages". You send them to servers, which is exactly what fine uploader helps you accomplish.